# непонятно как должны обьекты брать фон и текстуру у Background

Tags: java, ооп

Иерархия классов

```
Graph
--Point
---Circle
---Rectangle
----Ellipse
--Background
```

Класс Graph должен содержать абстрактный метод draw(). Остальные классы должны
его реализовывать, отображая атрибуты объектов в виде строки, например:

```
 Точка: x=10, y=20
 Прямоугольник: x=2, y=5, w=3, h=4
```

Класс `Point` и все дочерние должны содержать метод `moveTo(x, y)`, задающий
координаты объекта (например, центра окружности в классе Circle), а также метод
`move(dx, dy)`, изменяющий координаты на заданную величину (например, координаты
центра окружности в классе `Circle`).
Описать в дочерних классах все необходимые атрибуты, конструкторы и методы
(объекты должны иметь координаты и цвет; у класса `Background` есть цвет и название
текстуры).

непонятно как должны обьекты брать фон и текстуру у `Background`
Делать вместо меня не нужно, есть заготовки кода, просто непонятен этот момент в задании

Comment: Не очень понятен ваш вопрос. Скорее всего Background должен быть свойством в классе(тоесть используете агрегацию). Можете его в конструкторе задавать или setter ему сделать. Затем просто используете это свойтво в дочерних классах.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное ни как не должны брать фон. Фон — это не то, чем они закрашиваются, а то что вокруг них.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из формулировки задания, похоже, что `Background` никак не взаимодействует с остальными объектами. Так что, вероятно, вам достаточно закодить эту структуру классов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS. Я понимаю, задание не изменишь, но с точки зрения здравого смысла, `Circle` и `Rectangle` не должны наследоваться от `Point`, а должны содержать атрибут типа `Point`, т.к. круг и прямоугольник не являются разновидностью точки, а имеют точку в качестве центра. Аналогично эллипс - это не разновидность прямоугольника, но у эллипса есть прямоугольные габариты, которые можно было бы передать в конструкторе.